# How to use OpenCV to recognize boxes and count them (python)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

(disclaimers a lot of pictures, I don't know how else to explain it)

I am new to OpenCV and Image processing as a whole. I am trying to create a counter program that counts a [stack](https://i.imgur.com/d5VXtVu.jpeg)  of [carton](https://i.imgur.com/z4LpI0W.jpeg)  cigarette, but I am lost.

I have tried a lot of different method and watched a lot of tutorials, but I can't seem to mend those to what I need. I researched for some time and found a similar post that wanted to count a pile metal pipe and someone in the comments suggested using something called **local-binary-pattern** which performs a local comparison of pixel intensities using gray scale image and create [this](https://i.imgur.com/ORmeAhM.png) for an example. The 'analyze_boxes' one analyzes it to find countours and draws a box boundary to [visualize](https://i.imgur.com/w4eUNqn.png)  it.

```
def morph_operation(matinput):
  kernel =  cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))

  morph = cv2.erode(matinput,kernel,iterations=1)
  morph = cv2.dilate(morph,kernel,iterations=2)
  morph = cv2.erode(matinput,kernel,iterations=1)
  morph = cv2.dilate(morph,kernel,iterations=1)

  return morph
```

```
1. matinput- gray scale input matrix
2. width_radius, height_radius - radius of local neighborhood around each pixel.
3. stren - level of intensity
4. off - offset 

def lbp_like_method(matinput, width_radius, height_radius, stren, off):
    height, width = np.shape(matinput)
    matdst = np.zeros_like(matinput)

    for y in range(height):
        y_min = max(0, y - height_radius)
        y_max = min(height, y + height_radius + 1)

        for x in range(width):
            x_min = max(0, x - width_radius)
            x_max = min(width, x + width_radius + 1)

            roi = matinput[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]
            center = matinput[y, x]

            valid_cells = roi[roi > center + off]
            total = len(valid_cells)

            if total > stren * (2 * height_radius + 2 * width_radius):
                matdst[y, x] = 255

    return matdst
```

```
def analyze_boxes(matblobs, display_frame, size_threshold=200):
    blobs, _ = cv2.findContours(matblobs, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    valid_boxes = []
    wid = display_frame.shape[0]
    hei = display_frame.shape[1]
    for i, blob in enumerate(blobs):
        b_rect = cv2.boundingRect(blob)

        (rx, ry, rw, rh) = b_rect

        # Additional criteria for boxes can be added here if needed

        # Check if the area of the bounding rectangle is above the size threshold
        if (rw * rh > size_threshold) and ( rw * rh < int(wid/3 * hei/3)):
            valid_boxes.append(b_rect)

    if valid_boxes:
        print("Number of Large Boxes: ", len(valid_boxes))

        for i, b_rect in enumerate(valid_boxes):
            # Draw filled rectangles using cv2.rectangle
            cv2.rectangle(display_frame, (b_rect[0], b_rect[1]), (b_rect[0] + b_rect[2], b_rect[1] + b_rect[3]), (0, 255, 255), thickness=2)
            size = b_rect[2] * b_rect[3]
            
        cv2.imshow("display_frame_in", display_frame)

    return valid_boxes
```

I will attach the entire relevant code using **[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8fibJTs2)**.
// I have some extra function that crop the image to what I need and so on but basically.

Step-by-step goes like this in the file above.

1. Image -> crop it by drawing a rectangle and save -> make it gray
2. use 'lbp_like_method' and turn it [3rd attached image](https://i.imgur.com/ORmeAhM.png)
3. use 'morph_operation' and then use 'analyze_boxes'
4. [get boxes](https://i.imgur.com/w4eUNqn.png).

Now, the main problem. I don't know how to get boxes to match up. How should I proceed? Do you think this is the best approach? Am I overcomplicating the problem because of my lack of knowledge?

Also, I have tried Multi-Template Matching, which works but it does not recognize a lot of the cartons and I don't know how to optimize it.

**@toyotaSupra had a solution for problem that partially works but he did mention he was not completely done. Only thing left to do is optimize the canny edge method for which I am looking into "OSTU's method.
I will leave this page open so hopefully I can see different approaches from smart people on the internet. I will update this post for anyone else!**

Comment: what a great (and well formed) question. shame it is used on cigarette boxes.

Comment: I have 2 images. Just 25 lines.  https://imgur.com/a/b7ib6fg  and https://imgur.com/a/4fIl6s8. It is not widely to print each cartons. You can only get number of cartons.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Please guide me sir. I feel like I am overcomplicating the process, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @D.L thanks I know. Well, it going to be used to mainly help my parent run their tobacco shop. Hopefully, it will make counting and creating order sheets easier (although teaching them to use the app it going to be another task).

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a counter program that counts a stack of
> cartons.

box1.py.

Snippet:

```
import cv2

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('box.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(img, 19, 215)
# Apply adaptive threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(edged, 255, 1, 1, 3, 2)
thresh_color = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# apply some dilation and erosion to join the gaps - change iteration to detect more or less area's
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations =1)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh,None,iterations =1)

# Find the contours
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,
                                      cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                      cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and draw it
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area >33000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(img,
                      (x,y),(x+w,y+h),
                      (0,255,0),
                      5)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You may want to add counter.

```
i = 0
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area >33000:
       ....

        i += 1
        print(i-1) #substract from largest rectangle. Need to get rid of noises.
```

That will give total of 36 cartons.

Screenshot box 1 `cv2.Canny(img, 19, 215)`:

[image]

box2.py.

Snippet:

```
import cv2

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('box2.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(img, 9, 99)
# Apply adaptive threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(edged, 255, 1, 1, 3, 2)
thresh_color = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# apply some dilation and erosion to join the gaps - change iteration to detect more or less area's
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations =1)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh,None,iterations =1)

# Find the contours
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,
                                      cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                      cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and draw it
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area >33000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(img,
                      (x,y),(x+w,y+h),
                      (0,255,0),
                      5)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Screenshot box 2 `cv2.Canny(img, 9, 99)`:

[image]

PS: I haven't finished yet.

Comment: hey, thanks so much for this.  I also was wondering if there was a way to figure out the most optimal values for Canny method. I know I only gave 2 pics but there are more than 10 different brands with different writing. What is the best approach for that kind of problem?

Comment: great solution.  upvoted !

Comment: @SoloLord. You have to use more algorithms to prevent noise.